# H-bridge gate driver for an ESP32

Tags: dc-motor, h-bridge, esp32

I used an H-bridge for 12V 10A brushless DC motor.  The motor must run in both directions.

ESP32 ----- Multiplexer Circuit ---- Gate Driver ---- H Bridge ---- Motor

I have a few questions.

- Am I using too many components for a motor like this?
- Is the 10k resistors necessary for the P-channel MOSFETs?
- Are the diodes necessary?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I using too many components for an Engine like this?

No, if you want to change direction you need a H-bridge.

> Is This 10k Necessary for P Channel?

Can't say without reading driver datasheet.

> Is This Diode Necessary?

No, the MOSFETs have an integrated body diode.

That said, I'd use all NMOS with a cheap bootstrap driver like [NCP5359](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp5359a-d.pdf). This has automatic dead time, so it will prevent cross-conduction which can happen in your design if the FET threshold voltages are such that both NFET and PFET conduct during switching. The drawback is that it can't do 100% duty cycle, you have to flip the PWM once in a while to recharge the bootstrap cap.

For a motor, you don't want switching to be too fast due to EMI concerns, so a few hundred ohms gate resistors would be a good idea. With your design, that would worsen cross-conduction though. With a bootstrap driver, it's fine.

Also you don't have enough capacitance on the power supply rail. The caps need to handle the ripple current drawn by the H-bridge, so they have to be pretty beefy. There is also the issue of rising power supply voltage if you use the motor as a brake, that can be handled by monitoring power supply voltage with your micro and activating both bottom FETs to short the motor if power supply voltage rises above the safe limit.

Comment: Thanks your answers @bobflux . I can't make sense of 10K. Because some designers added, some didn't, and some increased their value. Your IC for  Laptops Power applications. is it OK for my applicaiton?

Comment: The IC should work, I've used a very similar one from the same product line at OnSemi to drive H-bridge before. The only gotcha is it won't do 100% duty cycle.

Comment: Thanks Bob. @bobflux